# Connect node.js with elasticsearch

Tags: docker, elasticsearch

***Scenario***
I am trying to connect to the `elasticsearch` from node. Below is the code snippet:

**connection.js**

```
var client = new elasticsearch.Client({
hosts:'localhost:9200'
});
```

Currently when my node application runs on docker, I get

> Elasticsearch error: No active connections

I want to pass the hosts value from docker run. How do I do it?

Comment: Where exacly is elasticsearch running? The localhost:9200 inside the docker container means it expects elasticsearch to be running under the same container, which doesn't seem to be the case I guess. For that you have to point it to the , which means 172.17.0.1 if on default bridge network, otherwise can be elsewhere..

Comment: The elasticsearch is running on bridge network on port 9200...I modified the host to 172.17.0.1 in connection.js file ..still I am getting 'No living connections' error. Is there a way to pass this 'host' environment  value during docker run

Comment: if elasticsearch is running on the same bridge as the js container just reach it by container name, i.e. elasticsearch:9200